# Solve $(3x+2)y''+7y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Solve $(3x+2)y''+7y'=0$

My first idea was to reduce into an euler-cauchy equation with $z = y' \rightarrow (3x+2)z' + 7z =0$

Let $e^t = (3x+2)$ then $z' = 3e^{-t}\frac{dz}{dt}$. The previous equation can be written as :

$$e^t\cdot3e^{-t} \frac{dz}{dt} + 7z = 0 \rightarrow 3z' + 7z=0$$

Now this is a separable differential equation: $z=C_2e^{\frac{-7}{3}t} + C_1$. Now $t = \ln(3x+2)$
$$z = C_2e^{\frac{-7}{3}\ln(3x+2)} + C_1=C_2(3x+2)^{\frac{-7}{3}}+C_1$$

Since $z = y'$ we get another equation $y' = C_2(3x+2)^{\frac{-7}{3}}+C_1 \rightarrow y= C_3(3x+2)^{-4/3} + C_2x + C_4$

Thus, since we only need one solution $C_4 = 0$, and re-writing we can get:

$$y = C_1(3x+2)^{-4/3} + C_2x$$

Is this a valid justification?

Comment: No need  for Euler since it's a first ODE with $z=y'$. And $z'/z=(\ln z)'$

Comment: You seem to be using $z'$ to mean both $dz/dx$ and $dz/dt$. This is rather confusing.

Comment: Also, $C_1=0{}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the Euler's trick  or you can simply write:
$$(3x+2)y''+7y'=0$$
$$(\ln y')'=-\dfrac {7} {(3x+2)}$$
And integrate.